# Value of support in frequent pattern matching

Tags: data-mining, pattern-recognition

I'm working with an extremely small & sparse dataset (~20k lines of transaction data) where about 92% of the lines contain a single item and the remaining 8% contain between 2 and 7 items. I want to use [`fpgrowth`](http://www.borgelt.net/doc/fpgrowth/fpgrowth.html) to analyze the patterns of the multiple items, but am running into a hiccup in understanding support as used in frequent pattern matches.

As I understand it, the support of itemset $S$, ${\rm supp}(S)$, is the fraction of times $S$ occurs in the transactions in $T$. Since I know that 8% of my data contains multiple items, I would suspect that support for frequent patterns would be small (indeed, it is not until I choose ${\rm supp}(S)\approx0.1\%$ that I get any results).

However, many of the tutorials I see on frequent pattern matching use ${\rm supp}(S)\sim10\%$ or larger. Should I be concerned about using such a small support value? Or should I process the data to remove duplicate single-item entries (reducing the dataset to ~1700 transactions) and use a larger support value on that data? Or a third, unknown-to-me option?

Answer (score 1):

Different data has very different characteristics.

Depending on these characeristics, different algorithms and approaches may be beneficial.

I would not be surprised if one-item-transactions are often removed in preprocessing for performance reasons. There is no way you get a meaningful association rule out of them.

A different characteristic to pay attention to is the granularity.

Consider a supermarket: association rules found on the item category level ("beer", "beverage" etc.) are more likely to be meaningful and statistically sound than on the individual item barcode level (single 0.3 can of brand A light beer).

Just use whichever support threshold you consider meaningful for you application; just make sure to not get millions of results. On many other data sets, a minimum spport of 0.1% would cause exessive results, likely to run into out-of-memory.